# Is 165aBmgtQJFDLkSYPU5C8jq5gpnAtHdKBh a scam Bitcoin address?

Tags: fraud

Is this bitcoin address authentic: 165aBmgtQJFDLkSYPU5C8jq5gpnAtHdKBh

I sent BTC to the address for Paypal funding but no response from them since yesterday.

Comment: Please don't use all caps in titles or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know.  Bitcoin addresses are designed to be used only once.  As you can see [here](https://blockchain.info/address/165aBmgtQJFDLkSYPU5C8jq5gpnAtHdKBh), nobody except you has ever sent coins to that address, and in all likelihood nobody else ever will.  And Bitcoin addresses are anonymous, so it is likely to be difficult to trace the address to its owner.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell if the https://blockchain.info/address/165aBmgtQJFDLkSYPU5C8jq5gpnAtHdKBh is bound an authentic PayPal address unless there is an xpub extended key correlation service that is rendered through a trusted channel.  Whatever the case, the 0.12 BTC deposited is gone.